# Write into SQLite database from other SQLite database via Python

Tags: python, sqlite

I have two SQLite databases.

```
[sava@localhost python]$ sqlite3 herostat.db 
SQLite version 3.6.20                        
Enter ".help" for instructions               
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"   
sqlite> .tables                              
archer_stat   warrior_stat  wizard_stat      
sqlite> select * from warrior_stat;
3000|300|9|9|5|1500|1700|700|200|120
sqlite> .schema
CREATE TABLE archer_stat 
  (con int, str int, wit int, _int int, dex int, mp int, pdef int, mdef int, patack int, matack int);
CREATE TABLE warrior_stat
  (con int, str int, wit int, _int int, dex int, mp int, pdef int, mdef int, patack int, matack int);
CREATE TABLE wizard_stat
  (con int, str int, wit int, _int int, dex int, mp int, pdef int, mdef int, patack int, matack int);
sqlite> .exit
[sava@localhost python]$ sqlite3 players.db
SQLite version 3.6.20
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> .schema
CREATE TABLE users
  (login text, password text, _class text, con int, str int, wit int, _int int, dex int, mp int, pdef int, mdef int, patack int, matack int);
sqlite> .exit
```

My Python 2.6 code:

```
conn = db.connect('herostat.db')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("SELECT * FROM warrior_stat")
cur_war = c.fetchone()[:]

conn2 = db.connect('players.db')
c2 = conn2.cursor()
c2.execute("INSERT INTO users(_class) VALUES ('warrior')")
c2.executemany('''INSERT INTO users(con, str, wit, _int, dex, mp, pdef, mdef, patack, matack) 
  VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)''', (cur_war, ))
conn2.commit()
c2.close()
```

What I expect:

```
player|password|warrior|3000|300|9|9|5|1500|1700|700|200|120
```

What I get:

```
player|password|||||||||||
||warrior||||||||||
|||3000|300|9|9|5|1500|1700|700|200|120
```

What am I doing wrong=

P.S. player and password writing early in process registration.

Comment: Where does that output come from?

Comment: I am see output into db players.db https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/61798016/executemany.png

Comment: And what command did you use to generate that output?

Comment: sqlite3 players.db -> select * from users;

Answer (score 0):

An [INSERT](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html) statement adds a new record to the table.
If you already have one record and execute two INSERTs, you have three records afterwards.

To change values in an existing record, use the [UPDATE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html) statement.